# C++ class construction by member initializer list with pointer to member address

Tags: c++, raii, legacy-code

I've got a C based library (Vulkan to be precise) that is initializing and setting values by passing their address to a library function as parameter. To prevent any leaks and to make sure that the clean up is called (even when some exception is happening somewhere) I want to encapsulate that value in a RAII class that calls the `create` and `destroy` library functions for it:

```
value_t value; // value must live somewhere else
library_create_value( value_t* value );
library_destroy_value( value_t value ); // must not be forgotten to call at the end
```

A C program would have no issues to work correctly here:

```
int main() {
  value_t myValue;                // fine, myValue lives on the stack of main()
  library_create_value( &value ); // and is ready to be used now

  // do all work, use myValue

  library_destroy_value( value ); // the required clean up
  return 0;
}
```

But now writing the C++ RAII wrapper I struggle to find the best solution to initialize the `value` as I'd normally do:

```
class RAII_wrapper {
  value_t myValue;

public:
  RAII_wrapper() : 
    myValue( library_create_value() ) // doesn't work here as it would normally do!
  {} 

  ~RAII_wrapper() {
    library_destroy_value( value );   // nothing special here
  }

  // other methods to use myValue would be here
}
```

Of course I could just do the creation call in the constructor itself and leave `myValue` uninitialized till then - but that is (called somewhere) "no good style".

What's the (officially) best solution for this task?

Comment: If the only reason you don't want to use the solution you already have working (calling `library_create_value()` in the body of the constructor) is because you're worried it's "no good style," then you might try asking this with your working code on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). What's "good style" over here on StackOverflow is Primarily Opinion Based

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you desire to wrap a pointer for an object on the heap even though that is not the usage in main() that you provided. A small change will allow this while also ensuring you only create the object once. The first example looks like you may construct the object twice, once with default constructor and again to modify it. See example below:

```
class RAII_wrapper{
    private:
        value_t *myValue; // This maintains same function call as example
    public:
        RAII_wrapper(){
            library_create_value(myValue); 
        }
        ~RAII_wrapper(){
            library_destroy_value(myValue); 
        }
};
```

Edit: If this wasn't a C library you could utilize smart pointers instead of the raw pointer to at least avoid the library_destroy_value() call.